# Copy debug path to object data visual studio code javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way in Visual Studio Code to copy the path to data in an object when debugging? Example: if my data lives in Object.user.city.name I would like to be able to copy that path after drilling down through debug console.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, under variables view, right click on the variable you want to export the path too and choose "Copy as Expression"

Thanks to @ConnorPeet on Twitter for the help!